# How to visualize arbitrary json using networkx?

Tags: python, json, recursion, networkx

I have a JSON object. For example:

```
js = {'a':'b', 'c':[10, 20], 'd':{'f':'k', 'l':'m'}}
```

Now, I would like to use `networkx` library to show a graph visualizing this JSON. In more details, for the given example I would like to have a "root" node pointing to `a`, `c` and `d` nodes. Then `a` node should point to the `b`  node, and `c` node should point to `10` and `20`, `d` node should point to `f` and `l` nodes and finally `f` and `l` nodes should point to `k` and `m` nodes, respectively. So, I want to execute the following:

```
G=nx.Graph()
G.dad_nodes_from(['a', 'c', 'd', 'b', 10, 20, 'f', 'l', 'k', 'm'])
G.add_edge('a','b')
G.add_edge('c',10)
G.add_edge('c',20)
G.add_edge('d','f')
G.add_edge('d','l')
G.add_edge('f','k')
G.add_edge('l','m')
```

I can do it manually, but how to do it automatically?

**ADDED:** Part of the problem come from the fact that `d` may refer to different objects. So, `d` as key in one dictionary is not the same node as `d` in another dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below should help, though for your additional part you will need to check for existence of key and modify (d, d1, d2).  If you have example of this I can edit.

```
%matplotlib inline 

import networkx as nx

js = {'a':'b', 'c':[10, 20], 'd':{'f':'k', 'l':'m'}}

G=nx.Graph()
for key in js.keys():
    G.add_edge('ROOT',key)

def walk(node):
    for key, item in node.items():
        if isinstance(item, list):
            for i in item:
                G.add_edge(key,i)
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            for j in item.keys():
                G.add_edge(key,j)
            walk(item)
        elif isinstance(item,str):
            G.add_edge(key,item)

walk(js)
nx.draw(G,with_labels=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I think in the function there should be return G (otherwise it does not work). There is also no root node (noting is pointing to 'a', 'c', 'd').

Comment: Ah my mistake you're right.. I've just edited.   If you have example of duplicate keys I will modify further